# Spark HBase Join Error: object not serializable class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I have data across two hbase tables and need to get the joined result from them.

What is the best way to get joined result.? 
I tried joining using RDDs, but it gave me error. 
I am getting the following error.

object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result

```
val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    hbaseConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost")
    hbaseConf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "table1")

    val table1RDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbaseConf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result]).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

    val table1Data = filteredRouters.map(  {case(rowkey:ImmutableBytesWritable, values:Result) => (Bytes.toString(values.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("col1"))), values) }).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

    //-------------//

    hbaseConf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "interface")
    val table2RDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hbaseConf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result]).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

    val table2Data = loopBacks.map(  {case(rowkey:ImmutableBytesWritable, values:Result) => (Bytes.toString(values.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("col1"))), values) }).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

    interfaceData.foreach({case(key:String, values:Result) => {println("---> key is " + key)}})

    // Got the table data //

    val joinedRDD = routerData.join(interfaceData).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK);
    joinedRDD.foreach({case((key:String, results: (Result, Result))) => 
      {
        println(" key is " + key);
        println(" value is ");
      }
    }
    )
```

StackTrace:

```
16/02/09 11:21:21 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 6) had a not serializable result: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result, value: keyvalues={
<My Data>
}); not retrying
16/02/09 11:21:21 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 6.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/02/09 11:21:21 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 5 failed: foreach at LoopBacks.scala:92, took 0.103408 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 5) had a not serializable result: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result
Serialization stack:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Solved this problem by using Spark Kyro Serialization.

I have added the following code

```
conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
            conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result]))
```

That solved the problem.

This would be solution for some other similar problems as well.